# Problem in running Python script from php within xampp htdocs folder

Tags: python, php, python-3.x, xampp, shell-exec

I am trying to run a python script from a php script both are located in XAMPP htdocs folder.

The python script is

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import numpy as np
ar=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(ar[0])
```

The php script is

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("python3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/test.py 2>&1");
?>
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/lampp/htdocs/test.py", line 2, in import numpy as np ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

However numpy is already installed in the system. When I run python3 test.py I get output '1' in shell output.

Where is the problem? I'm stuck for quite a some time.

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll see this comment, but would it be possible to try running this command `which python3` in your terminal? Then, would it also be possible to try running this command `echo shell_exec("which python3");` in your PHP file? Do the two output values from these commands match?